# How to dismiss progress bar once otp read from Inbox in android?

Tags: android

I have a Otp verification Screen in which I have a progress bar with timer ,what I want is to dismiss this progressbar once Read Otp from inbox if read successfully from Inbox then dismiss progressbar and execute Jsons Url if not then show progressbar with timer until not read sms from Inbox.for this I am using Broadcast Receiver .Kindly help me .

here is my code of MainActivity :-

```
 public class COtpAutoVerificationScreen extends Fragment {
    private static String s_szResult = "";
    private final String m_szOTPVERIFICATIONURL = "http://202.131.144.132:8080/resting/rest/json/metallica/validateOTPInJSON";
    public ProgressBar pb;
    private View m_Main;
    private int m_n_ProgressStatus = 0;
    private CRegistrationSessionManagement m_oSessionManagement;
    private String m_szMobileNumber;
    private String m_szEncryptedPassword;
    private CircularProgressView m_ProgressView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        m_Main = inflater.inflate(R.layout.otp_auto_verified, container, false);
        getUserDetails();// getuser deatails....
        init();// initialize controls...
        return m_Main;

    }

    private void getUserDetails() {
        m_oSessionManagement = new CRegistrationSessionManagement(getActivity());
    }

    private void init() {
        m_ProgressView = (CircularProgressView) m_Main.findViewById(R.id.progress_view);
        m_ProgressView.startAnimation();
        m_ProgressView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        pb = (ProgressBar) m_Main.findViewById(R.id.pb);
        final TextView tv = (TextView) m_Main.findViewById(R.id.tv);
        @SuppressWarnings("UnusedAssignment") final TextView validationText = (TextView) m_Main.findViewById(R.id.validatingmessage);
        tv.setText("00:00");
        //Initialize a new CountDownTimer instance
        long m_MillisInFuture = 30000;
        long m_CountDownInterval = 1000;
        new CountDownTimer(m_MillisInFuture, m_CountDownInterval) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                @SuppressWarnings("UnusedAssignment") long millis = millisUntilFinished;
                String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) -
                                TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished)));
                System.out.println(hms);
                tv.setText(hms);
                //Another one second passed
                //Each second ProgressBar progress counter added one
                m_n_ProgressStatus += 1;
                pb.setProgress(m_n_ProgressStatus);
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                // retreive user data from shared preferencce........
                HashMap<String, String> user = m_oSessionManagement.getRegistrationDetails();
                m_szEncryptedPassword = user.get(CRegistrationSessionManagement.s_szKEY_PASSWORD).trim();
                m_szMobileNumber = user.get(CRegistrationSessionManagement.s_szKEY_MOBILENUMBER).trim();
                // exc=ecuting request for otp verfiifcation to server
                new COtpVerify().execute();
            }
        }.start();
        // retreive progress bar count........
        int progressBarMaximumValue = (int) (m_MillisInFuture / m_CountDownInterval);
        //Set ProgressBar maximum value
        //ProgressBar range (0 to maximum value)
        pb.setMax(progressBarMaximumValue);
        //Display the CountDownTimer initial value
        tv.setText(progressBarMaximumValue + "Seconds...");
    }

    //  sending OTP to server to verify Otp
    private class COtpVerify extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        public JSONObject m_oResponseobject;
        public String m_szResponseAgentCode;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            m_ProgressView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            InputStream inputStream;
            try {
                // 1. create HttpClient
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                // 2. make POST request to the given URL
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(m_szOTPVERIFICATIONURL);
                String json;
                // 3. build jsonObject
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                jsonObject.put("agentCode", m_szMobileNumber);
                jsonObject.put("pin", m_szEncryptedPassword);
                jsonObject.put("otpCode", COTPVerificationDataStorage.getInstance().getM_szOtp());
                // 4. convert JSONObject to JSON to String
                json = jsonObject.toString();
                // 5. set json to StringEntity
                StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);
                // 6. set httpPost Entity
                httpPost.setEntity(se);
                // 7. Set some headers to inform server about the type of the content
                httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
                // 8. Execute POST request to the given URL
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                // 9. receive response as inputStream
                inputStream = entity.getContent();
                System.out.print("InputStream...." + inputStream.toString());
                System.out.print("Response...." + httpResponse.toString());
                StatusLine statusLine = httpResponse.getStatusLine();
                System.out.print("statusLine......" + statusLine.toString());
                ////Log.d("resp_body", resp_body.toString());
                int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
                // 10. convert inputstream to string
                if (statusCode == 200) {
                    // 10. convert inputstream to string
                    s_szResult = CJsonsResponse.convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
                    //String resp_body =
                } else
                    s_szResult = "Did not work!";
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
            System.out.println("resul" + s_szResult);
            // 11. return s_szResult
            return s_szResult;
        }

        // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final String result) {

            m_ProgressView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            try {
                m_oResponseobject = new JSONObject(result);// getting response from server

                getResponse();// getting response from server ...............


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        public void getResponse() throws JSONException {
            // if server response is successfull then......
            if (m_oResponseobject.getString("resultDesc").equalsIgnoreCase("Transaction Successful")) {
                // if server response is success then setting response odata in shared prefernce...
                getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new CLoginScreen()).commit();
                CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarSuccess(m_Main.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), "OTP verified successfully", getActivity());
            }
            // if response from server is m_szOtp mismatch.....
            else if (m_oResponseobject.getString("resultDesc").equalsIgnoreCase("OTP MisMatch")) {
                CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(m_Main.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), "OTP not found", getActivity());
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new COtpManualVerificationScreen()).commit();

                    }
                }, 3000);
            }
            // if response from server is m_szOtp empty then......
            else if (m_oResponseobject.getString("resultDesc").equalsIgnoreCase("otpCode Can Not Be Empty")) {
                CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(m_Main.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), "OTP not found", getActivity());
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new COtpManualVerificationScreen()).commit();

                    }
                }, 3000);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

and here is my BroadcastReceiver class:-

```
    public class CSmsBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String s_szTAG = CSmsBroadcastReceiver.class.getSimpleName();
    private static String m_szOtpCode;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        try {
            if (bundle != null) {
                Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                assert pdusObj != null;
                for (Object aPdusObj : pdusObj) {
                    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) aPdusObj);
                    String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                    String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();

                    Log.e(s_szTAG, "Received SMS: " + message + ", Sender: " + phoneNumber);

                    // checking sms sender address....
                    if (phoneNumber.toLowerCase().contains("+919971599707".toLowerCase())) {
                        // verification code from sms
                        m_szOtpCode = getVerificationCode(message);
                        assert m_szOtpCode != null;
                        String input = m_szOtpCode.trim();

                        Log.e(s_szTAG, "OTP received: " + m_szOtpCode);
                        COTPVerificationDataStorage.getInstance().setM_szOtp(input);// getting otp from SMS and set to otpverificationstorage class
                    } else {
                        return;
                    }

                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(s_szTAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Getting the OTP from sms message body
     * ':' is the separator of OTP from the message
     *
     * @param message
     * @return
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("JavaDoc")
    private String getVerificationCode(String message) {
        String code;
        int index = message.indexOf(":");

        if (index != -1) {
            int start = index + 2;
            int length = 6;
            code = message.substring(start, start + length);
            return code;
        }
        COTPVerificationDataStorage.getInstance().setM_szOtp(m_szOtpCode);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to send data from broadcast receiver to activity whenever desired message comes.you can make use of `interface` to communicate
In you BroadcastReceiver create interface like this

```
public interface OnSmsReceivedListener {
    public void onSmsReceived(String message);
}
```

add one method to initialize interface reference

```
OnSmsReceivedListener smsListener;
public void setOnSmsReceivedListener(Context context) {
    this.smsListener = (OnSmsReceivedListener) context;
}
```

use this reference to call function inside `onReceive()` method

```
 smsListener.onSmsReceived("Message Received!!!");
```

You are done with posting data ,now give implementation of interface in your Activity and dismiss your dialog.

```
public class SampleActivity extends Activity implements OnSmsReceivedListener
@Override
public void onSmsReceived(String message) {
    //Dismiss your dialog here
}
```

Other then this approach you can make use of some good third party library like [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) and [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/) which will make your work simple and easy.